# How to set virtual function in mongoosejs?

Tags: mongoose

For example,

```
var schema_t = new mongoose.Schema({
  sex: { type: String, enum: ['male', 'female'] },
})

schema_t.virtualFunction.isMale = function() {
  return this.sex === 'male';
}

// then I can use like this:
var a = new schema_t;
if(a.isMale()) {}
// instead of this
if(a.sex === 'male') {}
```

How can I define isMale() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to define isMale() as a function rather define it as a virtual attribute.

```
var schema_t = new mongoose.Schema({
 sex: { type: String, 
 enum: ['male', 'female'] 
 },
})

schema_t.virtual('isMale').get(function(){
if(this.sex === 'male') 
 return true;
else
 return false;
}


var a = new schema_t{
        sex:'male'
        };
if(a.isMale) {
 //code 
 }
```

READ MORE :[HERE](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/virtuals.html)